# Any known ways to convert CSV arrays to JSON files with nodes & edges

Tags: javascript, json, csv, graph

brief example

CSV file :

```
name, source, target
John  , A ,    None
Emma  , B ,    A
Mike  , C ,    A
```

theoretical corresponding JSON file :

```
{
  "comment": "example code",
  "nodes": [
    {
      "name": John,
      "source" : A
    },
    {
      "name": Emma ,
      "source" : B
    },
    {
      "name": Mike , 
      "source" : C
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "source": B,
      "target": A
    },
    {
      "source": C,
      "target": A
    }
  ]
}
```

resulting graph concept:

```
B  -> A  <-  C
```

the JSON file above is not absolute. It can have a variety of schemas. Above example is just very basic.

I am hoping there is a software or library that can easily turn CSV array to JSON files or something along those lines.

I have many CSV files that I'd like to turn into JavaScript graphs, but first I need a JSON input file that has data well structured. I would like to automate JSON file construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using [csvtojson](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson).

```
const csv = require('csvtojson');

const csvFilePath = 'test.csv';
var data = [];

csv().fromFile(csvFilePath)
    .on('json', (jsonObj) => {
        data.push(jsonObj);
    })
    .on('done', (error) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } else {
            formatData(data);
        }
    });

function formatData(data) {

    var formatted = {
        comment: "hello",
        nodes: [],
        links: []
    };

    data.forEach(function(r){

        //check for your empty or 'None' fields here
        if(r.name && r.source){
            formatted.nodes.push({ name: r.name, source: r.source });
        }

        if (r.source && r.target) {
            formatted.links.push({ source: r.source, target: r.target });
        }
    });

    //do something with the finished product
    console.log(formatted);
}
```

Comment: how to run this? node script_name.js ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

If the file `filter.jq` contains

```
[
  split("\n")                                                    # split string into lines
| [.[0]    | split(",")[] | gsub("[[:space:]]+";"")] as $headers # split header
| (.[1:][] | split(","))                                         # split data rows
| select(length>0)                                               # get rid of empty lines
| [   [ $headers, map(gsub("[[:space:]]+";"")) ]                 # 
    | transpose[]                                                # assemble objects
    | {key:.[0], value:.[1]}                                     # from keys and values
  ] | from_entries                                               #
]
| {
    "comment":"example code",                                    # convert objects
    "nodes": map({name,source}),                                 # to requested format
    "links": map(select(.target!="None")|{source,target})        #
  }
```

and `data` contains

```
name, source, target
John  , A ,    None
Emma  , B ,    A
Mike  , C ,    A
```

then the command

```
jq -M -R -s -r -f filter.jq data
```

will produce

```
{
  "comment": "example code",
  "nodes": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "source": "A"
    },
    {
      "name": "Emma",
      "source": "B"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mike",
      "source": "C"
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "source": "B",
      "target": "A"
    },
    {
      "source": "C",
      "target": "A"
    }
  ]
}
```